# Function pointer and default argument

Tags: c, function-pointers

Let's assume, I have a function with a prototype like (in `function.h`)

```
void function(int argument, bool flag);
```

This function has two variant behaviours, dependening on `flag`.

Early on, in a module (`module.h`, `module.c`) I called that function:

```
#include "function.h"

function(argument1, true);
function(argument2, false);
```

Let's further assume, I want to pass this function into a module, inverting that dependencies:

```
void (* funcPtr)(int argument, bool flag);

void setFuncPtr(void (* func)(int argument, bool flag))
{
  funcPtr = func;
}
```

Now I can have in `function.c`:

```
#include "module.h"

setFuncPtr(function);
```

And in `module.h`:

```
funcPtr(argument1, true);
funcPtr(argument2, false);
```

Is there a way to have two pointers, each pointing to the function, but with different, hardcodes values for `flag`? Like:

```
void (* funcPtrTrue)(int argument, bool flag);
void (* funcPtrFals)(int argument, bool flag);
/* Or, even better
void (* funcPtrTrue)(int argument);
void (* funcPtrFals)(int argument);
*/

void setFuncPtr(void (* func)(int argument, bool flag))
{
  funcPtrTrue  = func(argument, true);
  funcPtrFalse = func(argument, false);

}
```

(I now, this is no correct code, but should illustrated the desired functionality)

After Olis proposal, let's complicate things. `bool` is a typedef in `function.h`:

```
typedef enum {
  FALSE,
  TRUE
} bool;
```

Now I have to include `function.h` again to `module.c` in order to make it work again.

```
#include "function.h"

void functionTrue(int argument)
{
  fktPtr(argument, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Nope, not possible. A function pointer is an address. It doesn't hold any more information in it, as argument checking is compile-time, not run-time. Use wrappers, like Oli suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C doesn't have default arguments.

I assume there's some good reason you want two separate function pointers, rather than just directly calling `funcPtr` with the required `flag` parameter.  If so, why not just have two wrapper functions inside your module?

```
void (* funcPtr)(int argument, bool flag);

void setFuncPtr(void (* func)(int argument, bool flag)) {
  funcPtr = func;
}

void funcTrue(int argument)  { funcPtr(argument, true); }
void funcFalse(int argument) { funcPtr(argument, false); }
```

Comment: Okay, that helps alot. Just one more point. Suppose, `flag` is not a `bool` but a typedef enum. Now I need to include that typedef somehow, but with the function-pointer setter I wanted to invert exact that dependency..

Comment: @Oliver: So do you want your module to have a public API function along the lines of `setFuncPtr(funcPtr, argToUse)`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I want to hide enumeration, that controls the function. `function.h` should be hidden and the API of `module.h` should be usable without `function.h`. I want to be able to replace `function.h` without changing the interface of `module.h`.

Comment: @Oliver: What I mean is, how do you intend to inject the value of `flag`?

Comment: Ah, I see. As for the problem, where the question rised: Not at all. I only need one behavior of the function, therefore only one value for `flag`. This is why I didn't want to expose the whole interface with the enumeration to the "outside".

Comment: @Oliver: alright. But where does that one value come from? You either have to inject it externally (at some point), or module.c has to specify the value itself (in which case it needs to include the relevant header).

Comment: You are right. The value is specified by `module.c`, which includes the header. But with that solution, I can wrap `function()`. If I want to use `function` I only have to include `module.h` but not `function.h`. Your solutions solves all this. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use structures

```
struct funcstruct {
    void (*func)(int arg, bool flag);
    bool default_flag;
} funcstruct;

struct funcstruct funcPtrTrue, funcPtrFalse;

void setFuncPtr(void (* func)(int argument, bool flag))
{
  funcPtrTrue.func = func; funcPtrTrue.default_flag = true;
  funcPtrFals.func = func; funcPtrFals.default_flag = false;

}
```